# How can I Increase the Volume on an Acer Aspire 5?

Tags: audio, acer-aspire

The volume on my Acer Aspire 5 has always been an irritant, but lately it has become a bigger deal to me.

The speaker icon is all the way to the right, and the system sounds are also all the way up, so it's not a setting not being maxed out. I can hear it, but 10 is about the volume I would expect 5 to be. Is there any solution, or is that just the way it is with an Acer Aspire 5?

UPDATE:
I purchased an external speaker for $16; works great

Answer (score 1):

Right click the sound icon and select sound mixer, make sure the device is correct and at the level you want, also see if the apps are lower or at the same lvl as it.

If this does not work you might want to use the search option and look for the Realtek Audio manager and see if anything over there isnt what it should.

If none of those work you might wanna try reinstalling your audio drivers.
Hope this worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @henrique Thanks, Henrique; everything is maxed out.